# Failed to push to a View Controller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a very beginner to iOS development. I made a navigation application in iOS to view some details in another view when table view cell tap. I did the following code,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {
   LawyerViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LawyerViewController"];
   NSLog(@"%@",[self.myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
   dvc.lawyer = [self.myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

This is going to the next view. But `dvc.lawyer` is not null here. It's null on Next View page.

**Reading the Value in Next page**

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.lawyer.firstName);
```

[image]

How can I fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how you are reading the value of lawyer in next page?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",self.lawyer.firstName);` firstName is a String in Lawyer object.

Comment: maybe firstName is nil, not the lawyer itself. What do you see when you  log just self.lawyer?

Comment: Looking at your storyboard, I think you have a segue connected to your prototype cell right?

Comment: yeah. it's null. That is the problem I need to fix.Yes. it's connected.

Comment: Answer posted by Daniel should help. Sender will be your tableViewCell. So you can get the indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to instantiate ViewControllers in another way, if you use storyboard segues. You need to implement `prepareForSegue` where you can Access the segues destinationViewController like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // reference to the destination view controller
        LawyerViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any data 
        vc.lawyer = self.myObject[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]; // Not tested
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "You can't instantiate ViewControllers this way." ?? If identifier is set up in storyboard for view controller, this is normal way of vc instantiation.

Comment: If you have storyboard segues!?

Comment: Segues is another question - if you say "It's NOT THE BEST way" - i completely agree with you. However saying "You CAN't" means impossibility, and that's wrong, man

Comment: Ok but he needs to change his implementation to either method. I'll edit my answer

Comment: how can i get data from table cell and how to perform an action when table cell tap?

Comment: See my edit. To perform an action on tap you just need to call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"];`

Comment: `vc.lawyer = self.myObject[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];` gives me `expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'nsmutablearray *'` error..

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender; NSIndexPath *indexPath =  [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

Comment: Now there is no error. But output is null in my next page

Comment: What exactly have you implemented? I think this gets way too chatty here.